# How do you make a flying squid?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make "flying" squids on my server named "Derp". I don't know the commands, but I know you could make it by making a squid ride a bat.

I would be greatful if you could also provide me with a spawner command.

Comment: In the title you said that you want the squid invisible, is this a mistake?

Comment: Yes sorry I'll edit now

Comment: /summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"}} will get you a quid riding a bat. Not sure about the invincibility

Comment: What about making it have alot of health?

Comment: Alots aren't in Minecraft.

Comment: So it with stand being out of the water at least for like a minute

Comment: Can you increase the health of the squid?

Comment: I'm working on it. Creating unholy abominations with the console commands takes time.

Comment: If you want to add to your question please edit your post.

Comment: {ActiveEffects:[{Id: x ,Amplifier: x ,Durat­ion: x }]}

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> /summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},Invulnerable:1}

This summons an invincible squid riding a bat. The invincibility means the squid can't airdrown but the bat can still be killed.

If you want it to never despawn:

> /summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1}

To name it Derp, you'd need:

> /summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"},Invulnerable:1,CustomName:"Derp",PersistenceRequired:1,CustomNameVisible:1}

This is too long for the chat box however and it might be simpler just to spawn a Nametag and use that.

UPDATE: I took some info from the other answers and made this:

> /summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat",Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:-10,Duration:2147483648}]},Invulnerable:1,CustomName:"Derp",PersistenceRequired:1,CustomNameVisible:1}

Persistent invincible squid named Derp riding a persistent invisible invincible bat.

Fly my pretties, fly!

[image: Squids]

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: Minecraft is capable of so much more now than the last time I played...

Comment: -1 for bat not being invisible, +10 for the picture.

Comment: Can you make the bat invisible?

Comment: @SaintWacko Sure. Now ask me if I can wire the command block up to a repeater.

Comment: Wait, having problems with this. Bear with me.

Comment: Can you wire a command block up to a repeater... pretty please?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again :(

Comment: I decided to use loads of command blocks instead: http://i.imgur.com/qDOqmGd.png

Comment: It broke the game a bit: http://i.imgur.com/jDtkfBU.png

Answer (score 2):

A true flying squid would something like this, I think:

```
/summon Squid ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Derp",CustomNameVisible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,Riding:{id:"Bat",Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:-10,Duration:2147483647}]}}
```

Named, Invulnerable, Persitent, flying an invisible bat.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command.

```
/summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{Id:"Bat"},Invulnerable:1}
```

Haven't had time to test it, but it should work. If that doesn't work, you can just summon without the invincibility.

```
/summon Squid ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{Id:"Bat"}}
```

Comment: It doesn't but I think this is on the right lines.

Comment: " {ActiveEffects:[{Id: x ,Amplifier: x ,Durat­ion: x }]} " is this like on the right lines too? try it

Comment: {ActiveEffects:[{Id:11 ,Amplifier:5 ,Durat­ion: x }]} Is this right?

Comment: The problem isn't invincibility- it's getting a mob to ride something and be invincible without the syntax breaking.

Comment: Oh ok I dont know as much with command blocks

Comment: @Mincraftduuuuude I have updated my answer, if it helps, you can click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: Data tag parsing failed uneven curled brackets

Comment: @Mincraftduuuuude Add an extra curly bracket to the end.

Comment: Maybe its impossible..

Comment: Let me try again

Comment: @Mincraftduuuuude Nope, it's possible, see my above comment.